# Non-commutativity of operators, simultaneous eigenstates and degeneracies over finite dimensional Hilbert space

Tags: quantum-mechanics, operators, hilbert-space, commutator

Suppose, I have two operators $\hat{A}$ and $\hat{B}$ defined over a finite dimensional Hilbert space $H$. Also assume that both the operators have their own eigenstates that span $H$(existence of eigenbasis). Now, we take their commutator: $[\hat{A},\hat{B}]=\hat{A}\hat{B}-\hat{B}\hat{A}$. We could now have three scenarios :

1. $[\hat{A},\hat{B}]=0$
2. $[\hat{A},\hat{B}]\neq0$
3. There exist a null space(dimensionality >=1) of $[\hat{A},\hat{B}]$ which is a *proper subspace* of the underlying Hilbert space

I want to analyse each case separately and get some idea about the **nature of eigenstates**, **degeneracy** and **simultaneous solutions**.

---

**Analysis of 1**

In the first case, the commutator takes any state vector $\left|\psi\right> \in H $ to $0$. So, if we apply the commutator on $\left|\psi\right>=\left|a\right>$($\left|a\right>$ being an eigenvector of $\hat{A}$), we get:
$$\hat{B}\hat{A}\left|a\right>=a\hat{B}\left|a\right>=\hat{A}(\hat{B}\left|a\right>)$$
The second equality gives: $\hat{B}\left|a\right>$ as an eigenvector of $\hat{A}$ with eigenvalue a.

Further, we can have two more subcases:

a. $\hat{B}\left|a\right>=b\left|a\right>$ $\rightarrow$ This is a kind of *redundant* case where $\hat{B}\left|a\right>$ is no new eigenfunction of $\hat{A}$. Instead we can now say we have $\left|a\right>$ as a *simultaneous eigenfunction* of $\hat{A}$ and $\hat{B}$.

b. $\hat{B}\left|a\right>=\left|c\right>$ $\rightarrow$ This means we have *two linearly independent eigenvectors* of $\hat{A}$(namely,$\left|a\right>$ and $\left|c\right>$) with the *same eigenvalue*.(*degeneracy* of order two).

Mathematically, we cannot gain any other insight.So I find the following statement erronous.

Two commuting operators give rise simultaneous eigenfunctions.

Since, we donot know about the existence of simultaneous solutions, we could probably say:

Two commuting operators *admit* simultaneous eigenfunctions.(we donot know about their existence)

Also, I think its fine to say that **commutability is a necessary condition for existence of simultaneous eigenfunctions but not a sufficient condition**.(as my working clearly shows)

---

**Analysis of 2**

Here, there exists no state vector $\left|\psi\right>$ for which $\left([\hat{A},\hat{B}]\right)\left|\psi\right>=0$. This means that the existence of a simultaneous  eigenfunction will directly contradict the given *global non-commutativity*(here by global I am distinguishing case 2 from case 3 of the previously outlined scenarios).

Hence, this case means *absolutely* no common eigenfunctions.

In addition, there an interesting situation here. We now have a new non-null  operator(namely, the commutator)which will have its own eigenstates and eigenvalues. **If anyone can shed light on the properties of these eigenstates and their relation with eigenstates of $\hat{A}$ and $\hat{B}$, it would be nice**.

---

**Analysis of 3**

I have never come across anywhere talk about this case, but I have a hunch it might bear some relevance. Here are my ideas.

This situation exposes a new direction that I think must be understood first.

In analysis 1, we conclude about the existence of degeneracy or simultaneous eigenstates by letting the commutator act on an eigenvector of $\hat{A}$ or $\hat{B}$. We are **not checking for the action of the commutator on anything but an eigenstate**. Yes, action of eigenstate is known to us, **but what about the information derivable from its action on other state vectors?** They might also contain some information that is not related to the simultaneity/degeneracy of eigenstates of $\hat{A}$ and $\hat{B}$.Anyways, **we don't bother as atleast all eigenvectors go to zero**.

Here, **not all eigenvectors will go to zero**. Then, we have as a proper subspace of $H$ as the null space of the commutator.The classification of simultaneous solution or degeneracies will now only work for a subset of the basis of $H$. What about the other eigenvectors?(in the sense, **what conclusion can one draw about the connection between the eigenbasis of $\hat{A}$ and $\hat{B}$ due to this**)?

---

My question is evident in its analysis and how one can completely describe this situation considering all possible cases.Yet for a quick look my questions are:

1. What information can we extract about the relation between the eigenbasis of $\hat{A}$ and $\hat{B}$ from the commutation relation when we look at their(meaning the commutator) action on *non-eigenvectors*?(Analysis 1 and 3)
2. What is the relation between the three eigenbasis (namely, $\hat{A},\hat{B},[\hat{A},\hat{B}]$) in the 2nd case(when commutator is non-zero)?(Analysis 2)

Apart from the answer to the explicitly mentioned questions, comments on my analysis and further insights will be greatly useful.

Comment: Nitpick:  The way you've phrased it, conditions (2) and (3) can both be true:  a non-zero operator such as $[\hat{A}, \hat{B}]$ can still have a non-trivial null space. I would rephrase the cases as "the null space of $[\hat{A}, \hat{B}]$ is (1) the entire space $H$, (2) trivial, or (3) a subspace of $H$."

Comment: Related question on Math.SE: https://math.stackexchange.com/q/56307/11127 , https://math.stackexchange.com/q/236212/11127 and links therein.